# Can someone explain me this code intuitively?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I understand recursion and what the advantages it brings to writing code efficiently. While I can code recursive functions, I cannot seem to wrap my head around how they work. I would like someone to explain me recursion instinctively.

For example, this code:

```
int fact(int n)
    { if n<0:
        return -1
      elif n==0:
        return 1
      else
        return n*fact(n-1)
    }
```

These are some of my questions:

1. Let's say n=5. On entering the function,the control goes to the last return statement since none of the previous conditions are satisfied. 
   Now, roughly, the computer 'writes' something like this: 5*(fact(4))
   Again, the fact() function is called and the same process gets repeated except now we have n=4. 
   So, how exactly does the compiler multiply 5*4 and so on until 2 since its not exactly 5*4 but 5*fact(4). How does it 'remember' that it has to multiply two integers and where does it store the temporary value since we haven't provided any explicit data structure?
2. Again let's say n=5. The same process goes on and eventually n gets decremented to 0. My question is why/how doesn't the function simply return 1 as stated in the return statement. Similar to my previous question, how does the compiler 'remember' that it also has 180 stored for displaying?

I'd be really thankful if someone explains this to me completely so that can understand recursion better and intuitively.

Comment: I have but I am unable to find something which explains the concept in depth. All the ones I looked up did was define recursion, write a program to show its working and explain the principle behind it. But none of them made it clear why it's behaving the way it is behaving. I'll be glad if can provide me the link of such sources. Thanks

Comment: [Maybe this one helps](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/). The part you're missing is there is this invisible thing called a "stack" that tracks values and the funcitons as they recurse . The stack is used to know where to return when `fact` returns.

Comment: Looks like the question should be how recursive function being executed on a computer.

Comment: Check this link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/ especially the topic "Call stack"

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, for beginners recursion can be quite confusing. But, you are already on the right track with your explanation under "1.".

The function will be called recursively until a break condition is satisfied. In this case, the break condition is satisfied when `n` equals 0. At this point, no recursive calls will be made anymore. The result of each recursive call is returned to the caller. The callers always "wait" until they get a result. That's how the algorithm "knows" the receiver of the results. The flow of this procedure is handled by the so called stack.

Hence, in your informal notation (in this example n equals 3):

```
3*(fact(2)) = 3*(2*fact(1)) = 3*(2*(1*fact(0))).
```

Now, `n` equals 0. The inner `fact(0)` therefore returns 1:

```
3*(2*(1*(1)))) = 3*(2*(1)) = 3*(2) = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see a bit like this

The function `fact(int n)` is like a class and every time you call `fact(int n)` you create an instance of that class. By creating them (calling them) from the same function, you are creating a chain of instances. Once you reach break condition, those functions start returning one by one and the value they returned to calculate a new value in the return statement `return n*fact(n-1)` e.g. `return 3*fact(2);`